# Align un-ordered list nested to another un-ordered list and align to left side

Tags: css

I am having difficulty of aligning this un-ordered list inside another order list can anyone help me how to fix this below is my code thanks.

**css**

```
 <style>
    .dropbtn {
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color:black;
      color:white;
      min-width: 160px;
      overflow: none;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .show {display: block;}     
</style>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Html**

```
<h5>Menu</h5>
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li class="bullet-arrow"><span style="font-size: 90%;"><a href="/about">About us</a></span></li>
  <li class="bullet-arrow"><span style="font-size: 90%;"><a href="/blog">Blog</a></span></li>
  <li class="bullet-arrow"><span style="font-size: 90%;"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></span></li>
  <li onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn bullet-arrow"><span style="font-size: 90%;"><a>Terms & Conditions</a></span>
    <ul id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <li style="font-size: 90%;">Privacy Policy</li>
      <li style="font-size: 90%;">Service Agreement</li>
      <li style="font-size: 90%;">Terms Of Use</li>
      <li style="font-size: 90%;">Vendor Agreement</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `padding-left: 0` in your `.dropdown-content`. Its as simple as that.

If you want, you can try different values. I think in google chrome its `40px` by default

Update:

I am seeing `.dropbtn` is having a `padding: 16px`. Make sure it is not interfering. If it is try adding begative margin also.

Eg:

```css
ul ul.dropdown-content {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: -16px
}
```

Comment: not working still don't want to move ..remain center

Comment: That is strange. Is that all of your code? Can you paste the parent tags and their styles? Or better create a pen or sandbox? I think some other styles are interfering

Comment: margin-left: 0em;

Comment: No problem. Don’t forget to set the answer or upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

In `CSS`, try adding `.dropdown-content{ float: left;}` property. Complete code:

```
.dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color:black;
      color:white;
      min-width: 160px;
      overflow: none;
      z-index: 1;
      float left;
    }
```